# SVG background bug border space in Chrome [not actual]

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, background-image

### Seems fixed in fresh chrome/chromium

With this code you'll see vertical spaces on desktop chrome and horizontal on mobile.
All good only on firefox.

Can you give me any workaround for this?

```css
body {
    background: url("background.svg") repeat;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="98" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path fill="#444" d="M0 0h100v100H0z"/>
</svg>
```

98 value give bug space on desktop chrome.
100 value give bug space on mobile chrome.

[desktop chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yb1z.png)
[mobile chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMnms.png)

UPD: screenshot from **fresh** downloaded **100% scale** ratio chromium [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efr6I.png) where the **bug still existing**

Comment: Repl with code https://repl.it/@psydvl/chrome-svg-background-bug
Demo https://chrome-svg-background-bug.psydvl.repl.co

Comment: Check your zoom level in Chrome. I can only reproduce it at `110%` zoom level. It looks fine at `100%`.

Comment: Use `width='100'` for the svg element instead of `width='98'` or use `viewBox="0 0 98 100"` instead of `viewBox="0 0 100 100"`  Make sure to use the same aspect ratio

Comment: `width='100'` broke mobile version of site